# What are equal API for syscall.StringToUTF16, syscall.CreateFile and syscall.DeviceIoControl in mac

Tags: macos, go

I have the following Go code in Windows, and I want to port it to Mac. 
What are equal API for  syscall.StringToUTF16, syscall.CreateFile in Mac?

```
import (
        "syscall"
        "unsafe"

        "github.com/golang/glog" )
import "C"
const loggerDeviceName string = `\\.\Global\DGAPIMon`

var (
        loghandle syscall.Handle
        logdevid  uint32 )


func InitLogger() (err error) {
        // Setup the device id for the logger ioctl
        deviceType := 0x00008307 
        access := 0
        function := 0x72 // LOG STRING
        method := 0
        logdevid = uint32(((deviceType) << 16) | ((access) << 14) | ((function) << 2) | (method))

        devPath := syscall.StringToUTF16(loggerDeviceName)
        loghandle, err = syscall.CreateFile(&devPath[0], syscall.GENERIC_READ|syscall.GENERIC_WRITE,
                0, nil, syscall.OPEN_EXISTING, syscall.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
        if err == nil {
                glog.V(3).Infof("loghandle: %v logdevid: 0x%x", loghandle, logdevid)
        }

        return err }
```

loghandle and logdevid are using as below to log the message to a file.

```
    typedef struct tagLOGSTRING
    {
        unsigned long           level;
        wchar_t                 message[1024];
    }LOGSTRING;

    func LogMsg(b []byte) (err error) {
         var logstring C.LOGSTRING

         logstring.level = 0
         tmp := syscall.StringToUTF16(string(b[:]))
         for i := range tmp {
                logstring.message[i] = C.uint16_t(tmp[i])
         }
         err = syscall.DeviceIoControl(loghandle, logdevid,
                        (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&logstring)),
                        (uint32)(unsafe.Sizeof(logstring)),
                        nil, 0, nil, nil)
        return err

   }
```

Comment: This code doesn't look portable. What are you doing with the `loghandle` and the `logdevid` ?

Comment: updated above (in the question)